MySQL tempfolder Full
I have a mysql server hosted in an Azure VM. This is a slave where the data is being replicated from an on premise  Master. Configurations are mentioned below.
users are frequently getting an error The table 'F:\MySQL\temp\#sql262c_9ffa_20' is full . The same error also occurs during replication and replication stops. It gets fixed when I stop and start replication.
F drive is the where the Data is hosted and there is more than 1 TB of space left.
VM Configurations :
OS version Windows Server 2019 Datcenter
RAM size 256 GB
number of cores 32
Disk : Premium SSD LRS

MySQL is hosted on Azure VM OS version Windows Server 2019 Datcenter RAM size 256 GB number of cores 32 any SSD Premium SSD LRS
I have a mysql server hosted in an Azure VM. This is a slave where the data is being replicatied from an on premise  Master. Configurations are mentioned below.
users are frequently getting an error The table 'F:\MySQL\temp\#sql262c_9ffa_20' is full while quering the database . The same error also occurs during replication and replication stops. It gets fixed when I stop and start replication.
F drive is the where the Data is hosted and there is more than 1 TB of space left.
Another error I see in the error log is :

[ERROR] [MY-000035] [Server] Disk is full writing
'F:\MySQL\Data\mysql-relay-bin.019409' (OS errno 28 - No space left on
device)

VM Configurations :
OS version Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
RAM size 256 GB
number of cores 32
Disk : Premium SSD LRS

Things tried :
Looked for space and found there is enough space.
Looked for disk quota to see if the user has any quota on the data drive.

Additional DB information request, please.
OS, Version?
server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
H) Last 100 lines of your error log.
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

What query triggered the "full" problem?

Error Message "The table 'F:\MySQL\temp#sql262c_9ffa_20' is full"
If the temp table is InnoDB,The table 'F:\MySQL\temp\#sql262c_9ffa_20' is full message you are seeing has nothing to do with free diskspace. When an InnoDB table keeps a copy of data for the purpose of rollback and transaction isolation, there can come a point when the undo logs and rollback segments become logically full. When this occurs, InnoDB can no longer let the transaction continue.
I have addressed this many times over the years

May 31, 2013 : `ERROR 1114 (HY000) the table ... is full` with innodb_file_per_table set to autoextend
Mar 31, 2014 : mysql directory grow to 246G after one query, which failed due to table is full
Jun 16, 2014 : MySQL Index creation failing on table is full
Apr 07, 2015 : MySQL query INSERT INTO ... failed - The Table "x" is full

[ERROR] [MY-000035] [Server] Disk is full writing 'F:\MySQL\Data\mysql-relay-bin.019409' (OS errno 28 - No space left on device)
This message is an entirely different problem
If a slave collects too many relay logs, this could indicate one of the following scenarios:
Replication is Broken as seen in SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: No
Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL

Replication Lag is Way Behind as seen in SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G

Slave_IO_Running: Yes
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Seconds_Behind_Master: High number and increasing

Maybe Diskspace Really Ran Out in the Folder Where Relay Logs as Stored
When a temp table is populated, if diskspace runs out may freeze (See my old post from 2015 : How to fix a MySQL server with a full hard drive?).
EPILOGUE
I hope these things help you clarify what has been happening
